# Dell Studio 1558 Bluetooth Driver Issue

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bluetooth, dell-studio

I am using a Dell Studio 1558 laptop. Originally it had Windows 7 64-bit Home Edition but than I upgraded it to Windows 7 32-bit Professional Edition.

The problem I am facing due to this is that my system is not detecting the Bluetooth adapter.

When I install the Windows 7 64-bit/Windows Vista 32-bit drivers for Bluetooth it detects the adapter but only sometimes and most of the time it does not.

I am not able to find drivers for Windows 7 32-bit Professional Edition and thus not able to detect the Bluetooth adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I too had this problem.  I called Dell and they replaced the BT module.  It was bad.  I even had several blue screens due to it.  Call Dell...